# Kotlin - Unresolved Reference

Tags: kotlin, unresolved-external

[image]

I have question regarding about the `onStrike` variable. I declare `onStrike` in `UnionEmployee` as: `var onStrike = False`. Then, I go to the main function and create an object of `UnionEmployee as x`, but when I want to set `x.onStrike = true` it says

> unresolved referrence

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Hi! Please copy-paste the code instead of posting a screenshot of it! That makes it much easier to see what code is relevant for the question. Thanks!

Comment: `onStrike` is a Boolean variable and not a member of the class `UnionEmployee`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that your list is not `MutableList<UnionEmployee>`, but a list of some `UnionEmployee`'s supertype, for example just `MutableList<Employee>`. This could explain why you can successfully add a `UnionEmployee` there and call `work` method on an item of this list. If this is the case, then you should either declare your list as `MutableList<UnionEmployee>` or cast the obtained item to `UnionEmployee` if you're sure it will be of this type:

```
(list[3] as UnionEmployee).onStrike = true
```

Another explanation depends on whether `UnionEmployee` is written in Java or in Kotlin. If it's in Java, then `getOnStrike`/`setOnStrike` java methods are accessible in Kotlin as a property `onStrike`. If the class is in Kotlin, then these functions should be called from Kotlin as they were declared -- i.e. as functions. If you want a property in a Kotlin class, you should declare it as a property.